# Build a tree for string of parentheses

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I have a

```
typedef struct node
{
   node* br;
   node* son;
};
```

Given a string `char* str` which consits of sequence of `(`,`)`
I need to build a tree,for this string ,for example :
for string (()())() the following tree will be built:

```
       br        br 
node ----- node ---- NULL
    |son    |son
    |      NULL
    |   br        br      br
   node --- node --- node --- NULL
           |son   |son
          NULL   NULL
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: @Hbcdev - I thought about recursive solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tree is a little hard to read. I'm assuming that each parenthesis is a node and all nested parenthesis are child nodes.

Here's a simple algorithm:

```
We start with a root node representing the empty string.
For each char c in the string s:
    if c == '(':
        create a new child node
        move to the new created node
    else:
        move to the parent node
```

This should give you a good looking tree. Ofc you have to check if the string is valid, and compensate/correct when needed.

Comment: This solution is something I tried,my problem is how it will find tree for incorrect sequences of parentheses.this solution doesn`t find errors

Comment: do you need to detect if there are errors or where exactly they occur? cause given a good string, you should always endup at the root.

Comment: The issue, is that it is hard to tell if a string is correct or wrong before the end. backtracking to the original error is also hard since there might be different solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This code uses a stack to store nodes corresponding to open parens for which a close paren has not yet been seen. When it sees an open paren, it pushes a new node to the stack. When it sees a close paren, it removes the current top node from the stack, and makes it a child of its parent, which is the node that was just below it.

```
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    std::list<Node> children;
};

bool parse_parens (const char *str, Node *out)
{
    // stack of nodes for which open paren was seen but
    // close paren has not yet been seen
    std::stack<Node> stack;

    // push the virtual root node which doesn't correspond
    // to any parens
    stack.push(Node());

    for (size_t i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] == '(') {
            // push new node to stack
            stack.push(Node());
        }
        else if (str[i] == ')') {
            if (stack.size() <= 1) {
                // too many close parens
                // (<=1 because root has no close paren)
                return false;
            }
            // Current top node on stack was created from the
            // open paren which corresponds to the close paren
            // we've just seen. Remove this node it from the stack.
            Node top = std::move(stack.top());
            stack.pop();
            // Make it a child of the node which was just below it.
            stack.top().children.push_back(std::move(top));
        }
        else {
            // bad character
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (stack.size() > 1) {
        // missing close parens
        return false;
    }

    // return the root node
    *out = std::move(stack.top());
    return true;
}

bool print_parens (const Node &node)
{
    for (std::list<Node>::const_iterator it = node.children.begin(); it != node.children.end(); ++it) {
        const Node &child = *it;
        std::cout << "(";
        print_parens(child);
        std::cout << ")";
    }
}

int main ()
{
    Node root;
    bool res = parse_parens("(())()(()())", &root);

    if (!res) {
        std::cout << "Error parsing!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    print_parens(root);
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This uses `std::list` to store sibling nodes, which is easier to work with than what you have proposed. However the same algorithm should work there too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack to implement this, once you find left parenthesis,then add this node to stack. if again left parenthesis add child to top most element of stack. on right parenthesis remove node from stack. that's it.

Comment: inconsistent parenthesis can be found by checking stack node existence for right parenthesis.